# mkdir, pathname with symbol

Tags: c++, c, linux, embedded, mkdir

I  have a little problem, I need to make directory from my c code or c++, doesn't matter.
But directory name must contain characters like ':', ' ','.' in general current time,
when I try to create with `mkdir()` function I get EINVAL error, but from `system("mkdir ...")` everything is ok.
How can I solve this problem?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Can you give an example name that works with shell `mkdir` and not `mkdir()`? Also the man page doesn't even list `EINVAL` as one of the possible error codes, which makes it strange that you are seeing it.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet? Sounds like maybe the filename doesn't have the special characters properly escaped?

Comment: `mkdir()` returns zero on success, -1 on error sets *errno*.  EINVAL is not a documented *errno* value for mkdir().  If you use a fixed number of digits for each field aren't the separator characters somewhat redundant in any case?

Comment: @Clifford While neither POSIX nor the Linux docs mention `EINVAL` for `mkdir`, Linux does return `EINVAL` if you try to create a file or directory with a name that the filesystem doesn't support. It makes sense; I consider it a documentation bug.

Comment: @evghin Post an example (copy-paste a code snippet). Chances are that you misquoted your shell command and you're not actually creating a directory whose name contains the special character you wanted.

Comment: may be I was not right when I wrote EINVAL, from perror("mkdir") I have got "Invalid Argument", problem is that I am using FAT, but when I did system("mkdir...") I tried in my virfs, thats why it worked, thanks for all especially to Rob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different filesystem formats have different rules about what is and is not a valid character.  For `ext2` and its descendants, A file name may contain any character except for `'/'` or `'\0'`.

For FAT filesystem and its descendants, the list of invalid characters is larger, and includes `':'`.

Check to see what filesystem format you are using, and try running your program on a different filesystem.

Comment: How do you explain the fact that `system("mkdir ...")` works, but on the same file system `mkdir()` doesn't?

Comment: @Shahbaz - I don't explain it. I presume that his test is flawed.